# What's the real value in using BlockApps Strato?

Tags: blockapps

I installed the extension to Visual Studio 2015 to provide development support to smart contracts written in Solidity.

When discovering how to use this extension, and it's value, it became clear it uses a BlockApps KeyServer. This lead me to wonder why..and in answering that question I began to wonder what is the value of using BlockApps Strato over setting up your own Ethereum private net (for dev/testing); which only takes 5 minutes; compiling the contracts and using the Ethereum Wallet to test them etc.

So, I'm puzzled as to what the value-add of BlockApps Strato actually is as it doesn't appear difficult to write and deploy smart contarcts on Ethereum directly?

I don't get what BlockApps Strato actually brings to the party. I must be missing something; hence the question...

Comment: BlockApps is one of the most poorly documented software there is. I find it hard enough to get the hello world running. Did you get an answer to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclosure**, I work with BlockApps.

Each BlockApps node exposes a RESTful api to interact with the node. This allows you to deploy contracts/publish transactions with simple REST calls. Bloc-server also generates a REST api for each smart contract you deploy with it. This allows for a clean separation from your dapps frontend and smart contracts. That said just for simple dapps spinning up a private net is great, however when scaling a large application I've found the REST api and bloc-server really make development easier.

Comment: Is it possible to use BlockApps Strato with a private ethereum blockchain?

Comment: Do you mean connect a Strato node to an existing private blockchain?